# Fatal error with Custom Magento Module on one server but not the other

Tags: php, magento, module, fatal-error, member-functions

I am creating my own custom module in Magento and during testing on a Litespeed server (PHP v5.2.14) I am getting a `Fatal Error:  Call to a member function batch() on a non-object in ../../../BatchController.php on line 25` that was not appearing during testing on another linux server and a wamp server (PHP v5.2.11).

This one has stumped me. I am guessing it has something to do with the server configuration rather than the code itself. But i am just guessing. I was hoping someone here could tell me.

The only real major difference I could see, aside from the php versions and environment, is that the server that the error is on is using the Suhosin Patch. But would that be something that could cause this?

The line in question is `Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodel')->batch();` which is enclosed in an IF statement. `batch()` is a public function located in my model file.

If you need more code let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that is the line in question? Because `remove()` should be there. Are you 100% sure you are looking in the correct file?

Comment: I am 100% sure. `remove()` was there because I was seeing if it happened with another function called upon the same way, and it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a "non-object" error when calling a model, there's a problem with Magento's attempt to get your model class, and it is returning null. The reasons for this are not always apparent. If this worked identically on a normal LAMP stack, then the problem is most likely not in your code.

My first guess would be that the file does not have the proper permissions. Otherwise, it may have to do with resolving the classname. You could test this temporarily by calling the plugin directly like this:

```
$obj = new Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Mymodel();
$obj->batch();
```

If this works, then the file is readable, and you will want to go spelunking in the resolution of that classname. If it doesn't work, you have a problem with either autoloading or the declaration of your class.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: @Joe: Using the method above everything works. Are you able to elaborate on "spelunking in the resolution of that classname"? What would be the issue with just using the above code production? Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad that the code works for you. The argument against using it is that you have now successfully avoided Magento entirely, which may bite you down the road. Take a look at Alan's code about getting the classname, which is where your problem is. Your configuration is not being read (at least not the way you think it is), which needs to be corrected while you develop.

Answer (score 1):

Break it down.

You've tried to call

```
Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodel')->batch();
```

and PHP told you it tried to call the **method batch** on a **non-object**.  That means

```
Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodel')
```

isn't returning a Model object the way it's supposed to.

First thing to do is clear out your Magento cache on the server you're having problems with.  If your Module's config hasn't been loaded into the global config tree Magento will try to instantiate a Mage_Core_Model_Mymodel, and fail.

Second step is to make sure your module's `app/etc/module` file is in place.

Third step is to add some debugging (assuming a 1.4 branch) to the method that instantiates your objects and determine **why** Magento can't create your object

```
File:   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
...
public function getModelInstance($modelClass='', $constructArguments=array())
{
    $className = $this->getModelClassName($modelClass);
    if (class_exists($className)) {
        Varien_Profiler::start('CORE::create_object_of::'.$className);
        $obj = new $className($constructArguments);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('CORE::create_object_of::'.$className);
        return $obj;
    } else {
        #throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Model class does not exist: %s.', $modelClass));
        return false;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have cleared the cache with no luck. All files are in correct place. When I use getModelInstance it returns false.

Comment: @Jack: Then add debugging code in there and figure out why it's returning false.  Check what's string is in the variable "$className".  If the method's returning false it's because that class doesn't exist.